# Change Font Size of SVG Text Using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

So I'm trying to dynamically change the font size of an SVG text element based on its length using Javascript.

I've tried using .sytle.fontSize to set it, but nothing changes.
I've also tried setting different classes with larger font sizes and changing the class in JS, but that didn't help either.

HTML:

```
      <text id="Subtitle" text-anchor="middle" class="subtitle">
        <textPath id="SubtitleInnerHTML" xlink:href="#subtitleTextPath" startOffset="50%">
          MY TEXT
        </textPath>
      </text>
```

JS:

```
function ImageSubtitleSwap(content) {
   document.getElementById('SubtitleInnerHTML').innerHTML = content;  //This changes the text to whatever the user inputs, working correctly

   var str = String(content);
   var n = str.length;

   if(n <= 5) {
       document.getElementById('Subtitle').sytle.fontSize = "25px";
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.subtitle {
font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
font-size: 15px;
stroke: none;
fill: #c5eef6;
}
```

Comment: `sytle` should be spelled `style`

Comment: Jesus Christ, I hate myself sometimes.  Thank you so much.

I'm going to cry for a bit now.

Comment: No problem, did that solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  The text changes to a larger font size just like I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up just being a typo; the `svg` text element font size can be changed using the `style` property.

```
document.getElementById('Subtitle').style.fontSize = "25px";
```